# Opening image in Gallery app programatically shows low resolution

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

I download and save an image on button click in my app. This works fine. If I view this image via the Gallery app (or any other way) it looks fine.

However, if I try to open the image with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It prompts me what app I want to open the file with (Gallery or Photos). If I select Gallery, the image opens but is very low resolution. As the photo contains a lot of text, it makes it so you can't zoom in and read. If I select "Photos", it looks fine.

Is there anything I can do to make it work fine in Gallery?

Comment: `I download and save an image` If you dont show how you save we dont know what you do. Moreover if you just save an image to file system the Gallery app mostly does not show it right away. So what are you doing?

Comment: What is the file size and what is the resolution of the image? What kind of image file?

Comment: `If I view this image via the Gallery app (or any other way) it looks fine.` Mmmm... which file path is visible in details?

Comment: I didn't include that information because I don't see it as relevant. I've tried 2 methods of downloading the image, both work fine. It saves itself to a folder, where I can go and view it fine. If I open the gallery app and view it, it's fine. It's when I do it programatically with the code above, it shows but very low res. The image is about 1MB, 1100px x 2100px, jpeg. This implies to me that the download, file path, etc is fine and that it's something to do with the Gallery `Intent`

Comment: I had the same issue but with Google Photos. If I open a PNG and zoom it it looks terrible, but if I open the file with Sketch it looks great. Super annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was saving the image with no extension. As it was opening in Gallery I figured it knew it was an image, but as soon as I added ".jpeg" to the file name, it showed in correct resolution. Strange bug, figured I'd update just in case someone else was hoping to find an answer here at some point.

Comment: Very strange indeed.